# Can i set a threading timer with clock time to sync with cron job in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a cron job that runs at 12, 12:30,1, 1:30. So every half hour intervals on the clock.  I want to run a thread in my python code whenever the cron job runs.

I have seen examples where to run a timer every x seconds/mintues.But if I start my python code at 1:15pm for example if I set a timer for every 30 mins, the next time it will run is at 1:45pm. I want to thread to run at 1:30pm though. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost everything is possible, the real question is why do you want to do this? Keep in mind that cron scheduler won't necessarily execute jobs at precise times and furthermore, checking the time in Python won't necessarily correspond to cron's time, so if you need to execute something in your Python code **after** a cron job is executed, you cannot rely on measuring timings in Python - you actually need to 'communicate' from your cron job to your Python script (the easiest would be using datagram sockets)

But, if you want to simulate cron scheduler in Python, one way to do it is to use the `datetime` module to get the current time and then calculate the amount of `time.sleep()` you need before your command fires again, e.g.:

```
def schedule_hourly_task(task, minute=0):
    # get hourly offset in seconds in range 1-3600
    period = ((60 + minute) % 60) * 60 or 3600
    while True:
        # get current time
        current = datetime.datetime.now()
        # count number of seconds in the current hour
        offset = (current - current.replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)).total_seconds()
        # calculate number of seconds til next period
        sleep = period - offset % period
        if offset + sleep > 3600:  # ensure sleep times apply to full hours only
            sleep += 3600 % period
        # sleep until the next period
        time.sleep(sleep)
        # run the task, break the loop and exit the scheduler if `False` is returned
        if not task():
            return
```

Then you can use use it to run whatever task you want at any `full_hour + minute` offset. For example:

```
counter = 0
def your_task():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    if counter > 2:
        return False
    return True

schedule_hourly_task(your_task, 15)
```

And it will execute `your_task()` function every 15 minutes until `your_task()` returns `False` - in this case at `hh:15`, `hh:30` and `hh:45` before exiting. In your case, calling `schedule_hourly_task(your_task, 30)` will call the `your_task()` function every full 30 minutes for as long as `your_task()` returns `True`.