# Timer to run every 5 minutes (0,5,10,15,etc) 24/7 non stop

Tags: python, json, multithreading, ifttt

We're trying to get notifications on the cellphone (using IFTTT) when there are problems with an API service.
This is the system status request:

```
status = client.get_system_status()
print(status)
```

And this is the json response:

```
{'msg': 'normal', 'status': 0}
```

When the system status enters Maintenance mode, the response change to 'status' : 1.

We want to check the system status every round 5 minutes (0,5,10,15,etc) 24/7 non stop, and if a system maintenance is found ('status': 1), send the notification using the code below:

```
import requests
data = {"value1":"Attention: System Maintenance"}
response = requests.post('https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/23423/with/key/dLL84tqq34tQlpcwsNPR_mDzoD_2D5yRLv8LNG8NVDElxbsfMi', json=data)
print (response.status_code)
```

Which would be the best way to do it?

Comment: https://github.com/dbader/schedule

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i set a threading timer with clock time to sync with cron job in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42380494/can-i-set-a-threading-timer-with-clock-time-to-sync-with-cron-job-in-python)

Comment: @n1c9 Thank you very much for the reference. Do you know how to control the start to use round 5 mins intervals only, like 0,5,10,15,20, etc?